# Get back full URI from Addressable object?

Tags: ruby, addressable-gem

If I have an addressable object like this:

```
uri = Addressable::URI.parse("http://example.com/path/to/resource/")
```

How would I get back the "http://example.com/path/to/resource/" - I have looked at uri.methods, but I fail to see which one would I use to get back the full URI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `to_s` method:

```
uri = Addressable::URI.parse("http://example.com/path/to/resource/")
uri.to_s
# => "http://example.com/path/to/resource/"
```

See [`URI` - basic example](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#module-URI-label-Basic+example).

Comment: oh gosh. easy but I couldn't figure it out. Thanks.